# How to change the style of tabs on android 2.3- actionbarsherlock

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-tabs

Hi I want to change the tabs in android <=2.3 because they take too much space

[image]

to

[image]

And I also want to modify it's background and icons.

I am using `actiobarsherlock` library.

Here is what I tried

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <TabWidget
            android:id="@android:id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:layout_weight="0"
            style="@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Example"
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:tabStripEnabled="false" />

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0" />

        <com.mainapp.CustomViewPager
            android:id="@+id/pager"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
    </LinearLayout>

</TabHost>
```

Style

```
<style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Example" parent="@style/Widget.Sherlock.Light.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_example</item>
    </style>
```

-

```
    <!-- Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_focused_example" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="false" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_focused_example" />

    <!-- Pressed -->
    <!--    Non focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_example" />
    <item android:state_focused="false" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_example" />

    <!--    Focused states -->
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="false" android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_unselected_pressed_example" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_selected="true"  android:state_pressed="true" android:drawable="@drawable/tab_selected_pressed_example" />
</selector>
```

Thanks!

Comment: What's the style you use?

Comment: And the drawables used in the selector are?

Comment: http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/  I used this website to generate these drawable. However if I remove the line `style="@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Example"` from TabHost then nothing seems to change.

Comment: If removing the style doesn't change things then something else is messing the tabs. One thing that I find strange is why did you use the `android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"` property?

Comment: Just because this layout start from below `ActionBar`. By giving it a margin the tabs are below the `actionbar`. If I remove it then tabs and action bar are overlapping with each other.

Comment: I don't see why the content of the action bar would overlap your app's tabs. Maybe you can write a small project which shows the behavior you face?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Update:

> You use actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
>   My all three fragments use
>   actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST); So tabs
>   does not show. I tried to show both tab and list navigation but now
>   working. I want to use tabs navigation plus navigation mode list in my
>   fragments. How can I achieve it? – john smith 1 hour ago

You can not have both. What I would recommend in this case is

a) Instead of using Navigation_mode_list you could start using the navigation drawer/slidingmenu pattern.

https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/navigation-drawer.html

b) Instead of tabs use the viewpager + viewpager strips. Then you can use Naviagation_mode_list.

c) Instead of using navigation_mode_list, you can have an actionbar menu item which someone can pressed that will launch a dialog.

### Original

Tabs in the ActionBar and Tabs in Tabhost are actually **different** and do not use the same styles set. This would explain why your changing the style doesn't do anything.

Now there a couple approach you can do to get that Holo like style.

- You can use ActionBarSherlock.Tabs + Fragments and not use TabHost at all. (My Recommendation)
- You can style the Tabhost directly using [Holo Colors Generator](http://android-holo-colors.com/) (Actually more effort require for specific TabHosts)

The reason why I recommenced (ActionBarSherlock.Tabs + Fragments) is that how Android development is going towards. Using Fragments allow you to have full reusable chuck of code. Also the viewpager lets you have that slick swiping action to add interactivity. Here's a code to implement it and tested on 2.2 emulator.

```
package com.example.stackoverflow;

import java.util.Locale;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentTransaction; 
import android.support.v4.view.ViewPager;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.ActionBar.TabListener;
import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockFragmentActivity;

public class MainActivity extends SherlockFragmentActivity implements
    TabListener {

/**
 * The {@link android.support.v4.view.PagerAdapter} that will provide
 * fragments for each of the sections. We use a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentPagerAdapter} derivative, which
 * will keep every loaded fragment in memory. If this becomes too memory
 * intensive, it may be best to switch to a
 * {@link android.support.v4.app.FragmentStatePagerAdapter}.
 */
SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

/**
 * The {@link ViewPager} that will host the section contents.
 */
ViewPager mViewPager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    // Set up the action bar.
    final ActionBar actionBar = getSupportActionBar();
    actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);

    // Create the adapter that will return a fragment for each of the three
    // primary sections of the app.
    mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(
            getSupportFragmentManager());

    // Set up the ViewPager with the sections adapter.
    mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.pager);
    mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

    // When swiping between different sections, select the corresponding
    // tab. We can also use ActionBar.Tab#select() to do this if we have
    // a reference to the Tab.
    mViewPager
            .setOnPageChangeListener(new ViewPager.SimpleOnPageChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void onPageSelected(int position) {
                    actionBar.setSelectedNavigationItem(position);
                }
            });

    // For each of the sections in the app, add a tab to the action bar.
    for (int i = 0; i < mSectionsPagerAdapter.getCount(); i++) {
        // Create a tab with text corresponding to the page title defined by
        // the adapter. Also specify this Activity object, which implements
        // the TabListener interface, as the callback (listener) for when
        // this tab is selected.
        actionBar.addTab(actionBar.newTab()
                .setText(mSectionsPagerAdapter.getPageTitle(i))
                .setTabListener(this));
    }
}

@Override
public void onTabSelected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
    // When the given tab is selected, switch to the corresponding page in
    // the ViewPager.
    mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
}

@Override
public void onTabUnselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

@Override
public void onTabReselected(ActionBar.Tab tab,
        FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction) {
}

/**
 * A {@link FragmentPagerAdapter} that returns a fragment corresponding to
 * one of the sections/tabs/pages.
 */
public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        // getItem is called to instantiate the fragment for the given page.
        // Return a DummySectionFragment (defined as a static inner class
        // below) with the page number as its lone argument.
        Fragment fragment = new DummySectionFragment();
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        args.putInt(DummySectionFragment.ARG_SECTION_NUMBER, position + 1);
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        // Show 3 total pages.
        return 4;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        Locale l = Locale.getDefault();
        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            return "Simple";
        case 1:
            return "Contacts";
        case 2:
            return "Custom";
        case 3:
            return "Throttle";
        }
        return null;
    }
}

/**
 * A dummy fragment representing a section of the app, but that simply
 * displays dummy text.
 */
public static class DummySectionFragment extends Fragment {
    /**
     * The fragment argument representing the section number for this
     * fragment.
     */
    public static final String ARG_SECTION_NUMBER = "section_number";

    public DummySectionFragment() {
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_main_dummy,
                container, false);
        TextView dummyTextView = (TextView) rootView
                .findViewById(R.id.section_label);
        dummyTextView.setText(Integer.toString(getArguments().getInt(
                ARG_SECTION_NUMBER)));
        return rootView;
    }
}

 }
```

[image: Viewpager actionbar tabs style on 2.2 device]

To generate this code, I used File->New-> Other - > Android Folder -> Android - Activity - > Blank Activity -> Navigation style set to Fixed Tabs + swipe. However you can't use this directly with actionbarsherlock, as you need to replace Actionbar variable with getSupportActionBar like I done so in the code above.

Comment: You use  `actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);` My all three fragments use  `actionBar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_LIST);` So tabs does not show. I tried to show both tab and list navigation but now working. I want to use tabs navigation plus navigation mode list in my fragments. How can I achieve it?

Comment: I update my answer. This is quite a long gap between the original day I submitted my answer. haha

Comment: Hi Jerad, thanks for your suggestions. Here is my app in play store https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.screen.callerpro These tabs do not look good. I am working on changing the whole UI of the app. I can't use sliding drawer or dialog menu. May be viewpager strips fit my need but it will take lots of time.